# Natural language generation evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, lstm

I was making a natural language generator using LSTM networks but now I am stuck in the part , how to evaluate my output. Suppose i have a input training data-set that consists of a dialogue act representation and the correct output for that particular dialogue act. Now suppose i generate a output sentence y from my LSTM network, so how to evaluate that sentence in comparison to the one in the data-set. I mean is there any way to compare output so that I can use gradient descent to train my weights.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you find the answer, you'll be able to write a nice paper about it since that's kind of an open research question right now. :)

To my best knowledge, your evaluation has to combine syntactic and semantic plausibility of the output, context-coherence, personality consistency and discourse dynamic progression. There's no consensus on how to optimally measure these, but there's plenty of current papers on the topic.

Related introductory read by Liu et al: https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08023

Comment: On github i saw various projects on natural language generation, google also uses it and they shared a video on that. Can you help me if you know about the functioning of their models ? Or any similar stuff you have worked upon.

Comment: The models you're talking about are bleeding edge and not really common knowledge. What are you trying to build a model for exactly?

Comment: i am trying to build the model for generating a natural language if i am given a dialogue act representation. Its similar to generating grammatically correct sentence if you have a structured data.

Comment: I am building a model that takes input a DA representation and generates a natural language. For example let the da representation of the data is  inform(name='the carriage inn';phone='4155528600') then one of the possible outputs is the carriage inn is a nice place their phone number is 4155528600